# The root page doesn't change

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First I have local application in `Sites/application1` and I make repository on bitbucket with development branch and push my application to my repo, and then I make new directory `Sites/new_version/application1` and get clone from development branch. On new directory I create new branch 'new_version' and checkout to new branch. So I have two applications with same database on my local now

```
Sites/application1 -> development branch
Sites/new_version/application1 -> new_version branch
```

I have tried to change root page on new_version application, and run rails server, but the page doesn't change to new root page, I'm sure I have changed `routes.rb` like this

```
# old
# root 'welcome#index'
root 'welcome#new_version'
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 layout Proc.new{ ['new_version'].include?(action_name) ? 'application_new_version' : 'application' }

 def new_version
 end

 def index
 end

end
```

I tried to change my route like this

```
get 'new_version', to: => 'welcome#new_version'
```

I can access `localhost:3000/new_version` .

Why root page doesn't change with new layout and new action?

Comment: Do you want to create a whole new version of the application or do you just want to try a new layout? Because putting one Rails app inside another doesn't really make sense. Why not just create a new git branch for your new version?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put this

```
layout Proc.new{ 
  logger.info "Action name: #{action_name}"
  if ['new_version'].include?(action_name) 
    'application_new_version'
  else
    'application' 
  end
}
```

And tell us what you're getting in the console with action_name?